# Web Api GET Verb 405 Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-405, http-verbs

I have sort of the opposite issue of most other people. My failing verbs are GET and POST. PUT and DELETE are allowed for some reason. Here's my related web.config.

```
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="static dist files" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="C:\Source\PRISM\DEV\PRISM\Service\PRISM.Service\dist\{R:1}" matchType="IsFile" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="index.html as document root" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I've also tried adding the remove name="WebDAV" but it did nothing.

Comment: Are you running this locally and it's failing or?

Answer (score 0):

So it was not an error 405 issue. I had a method signature that did not match my route, specifically the parameter id. My get method had a different parameter name.

Comment: If that's the case, you should just delete your question since it doesn't really provide value to the site.